# Как выполнить команду mongorestore в windows?

Tags: mongodb, windows-10

Сразу оговорюсь что я никогда не работал с mongodb через windows. Мне необходимо загрузить дамп. В linux я делал это командой `mongorestore --db=parsers --nsInclude="*.bson" путь  к  дампу` В windows та же команда выдаёт ошибку

```
"mongorestore" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Как мне выполнить эту команду под windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С версии 4.4 эти инструменты больше не являются частью базового пакета и должны устанавливаться отдельно, так что воспользуйтесь ссылкой https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

> The MongoDB Database Tools are a collection of command-line utilities
> for working with a MongoDB deployment. These tools release
> independently from the MongoDB Server schedule enabling you to receive
> more frequent updates and leverage new features as soon as they are
> available.

> Инструменты базы данных MongoDB - это набор утилит командной строки
> для работы с развертыванием MongoDB. Эти инструменты выпускаются
> независимо от выпусков сервера MongoDB, что позволяет получать более
> частые обновления и использовать новые функции, как только они станут
> доступны.